# Wp_Query not showing featured post

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am currently working through a wordpress course and I am building the homepage of the wordpress website and have ran into an issue. I am trying to use the WP Query class to create a featured post however, the post is not being displayed. Here's my code.

```
<section class="middle-area">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <aside class="sidebar col-md-3 h-100">

                        <?php 
                        
                        // Require a file called sidebar-home.php
                        get_sidebar( 'home' ); 

                        ?>
                            
                    </aside>
                    <div class="news col-md-9">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="container">
                            <?php 

                            $featured = new WP_Query( 'post_type=post&posts_per_page=1&cat=4,11' );

                            if( $featured->have_posts() ):
                                while( $featured->have_posts() ): $featured->the_post();
                            ?>

                            <div class="col-12">
                                <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'featured' ); ?>
                            </div>

                            <?php
                                endwhile;
                                wp_reset_postdata();
                            endif;


                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    </div>                          
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

The content-featured file

```
<article <?php post_class( array( 'class' => 'featured' ) ); ?>>
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<div class="thumbnail">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'large', array( 'class' => 'img-fluid' ) ); ?>
</div>

<div class="meta-info">
    <p>
        by <span><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span> 
        Categories: <span><?php the_category( ' ' ); ?></span>
        <?php the_tags( ' Tags: <span>', ', ', '</span>' ); ?>
    </p>
    <p><span><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></p>      
</div>
<p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
```

Comment: What is the current output?

Comment: Nothing is been displayed.